# Is there a more precise approximation to $\frac{\sin(\pi y/360)}{\sin(\pi x/360)}$ than $\sqrt[90^2]{\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt2}}^{(x^2-y^2)}\frac{y}{x}$?

Tags: trigonometry

If we have $s$ semicircle with the diameter $AB$ (with length $1$) and the center $O$, then we can approximate
$$\frac{\operatorname{chord} AC}{\operatorname{chord} AD} \;=\; \sqrt[90^2]{\frac{{\pi}}{2\sqrt{2}}}^{(x^2-y^2)}\cdot \frac{y}{x} \tag1$$
where $x$ represents the value of the $\angle AOC$, and $y$ represents the value of the angle $\angle AOD$, in degrees.

For example, if $x=60$ and $y=120$, we will get $1.7386\ldots$.

> Is there formula with a more precise approximate value for $\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{360}y\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{360}x\right)}$ than $(1)$?

Comment: I don't see a question.  What are you asking?

Comment: I notice that [you asked this question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4068163/409). In the future, please be aware that re-posting a question is not the appropriate way to attract more attention to it. Rather, you should edit the original to make substantive improvements. An edit "bumps" the question to the top of the Unanswered Queue as if it were a new question, so you get the benefit of a re-post without cluttering the site with duplicates. (Note, however, that non-substantive edits *just* to "bump" a question are inappropriate.)

Comment: Thanks for edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Written in a more traditional way, your formula write
$$z_1=\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{360}y\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{360}x\right)}=\frac y x\left(\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)^{\frac{x^2-y^2}{8100} }\tag 1$$ where $x$ and $y$ are in degrees.

Using Bhaskara sine approximation formula which was proposed more than $\color{red}{\large 1400}$ years ago, it would write
$$z_2=\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{360}y\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{360}x\right)}=\frac y x\,\,\frac { (360-y)  }{ (360-x)  }\,\,\frac{y^2-360 y+162000 } {x^2-360 x+162000 }\tag 2$$ Applied to your case $y=120$ and $x=60$
$$(1) \implies \frac{8}{\pi ^{4/3}}=1.73870\implies \text{error }=0.38\text{%}$$
$$(2) \implies \frac{64}{37}=1.72973\implies \text{error }=0.13\text{%}\qquad \text{( 3 times better)}$$

Suppose now that $y=x+\epsilon$. Expanding as series, your formula would give

$$z_1=1+  \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x \log (\pi )}{4050}+\frac{x \log
   (2)}{2700}\right)\epsilon+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ while
$$z_2=1+\frac{324000 (x-180) }{(x-360) x \left(x^2-360
   x+162000\right)} \epsilon +O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ wile the exact would be
$$z= 1+\frac{1}{360} \pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi  x}{360}\right) \epsilon +O\left(\epsilon
   ^2\right)$$ and this always favor $(2)$ compared to $(1)$.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: You can read the last part 1st if you only want to get the better approximation.)

Let $$f(x, y) = \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{360} y}{\sin \frac{\pi}{360} x}$$ to be the function we want to approximate.

We begin by observing that for all $u \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$\sin \left(u + n\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \begin{cases}
\sin u \text{ when } n = 4k \text{ for some } k \\
\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - u\right) \text{ when } n = 4k + 1 \text{ for some } k \\
-\sin u \text{ when } n = 4k + 2 \text{ for some } k \\
-\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - u\right) \text{ when } n = 4k + 3 \text{ for some } k
\end{cases}$$
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore,
$$f\left(x + 180n, y\right) =
\begin{cases}
f(x, y) \text{ when } n = 4k \text{ for some } k \\
f(180 - x, y) \text{ when } n = 4k + 1 \text{ for some } k \\
-f(x, y) \text{ when } n = 4k + 2 \text{ for some } k \\
-f(180 - x, y) \text{ when } n = 4k + 3 \text{ for some } k
\end{cases}$$
and
$$f\left(x, y + 180n\right) =
\begin{cases}
f(x, y) \text{ when } n = 4k \text{ for some } k \\
f(x, 180 - y) \text{ when } n = 4k + 1 \text{ for some } k \\
-f(x, y) \text{ when } n = 4k + 2 \text{ for some } k \\
-f(x, 180 - y) \text{ when } n = 4k + 3 \text{ for some } k
\end{cases}$$
where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence we only need to care about the value of $f$ inside the square $(0, 180] \times [0, 180]$. We've excluded $x = 0$ because $f$ is not defined there.

---

By [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder), we know $\sin \frac{\pi}{360} u$ has Taylor polynomial
$$T_{2n + 2}(u) = T_{2n + 1}(u) = \sum_{k = 0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k + 1)!} \left(\frac{\pi}{360} u\right)^{2k + 1}$$
with remainder
$$|R_{2n + 2}(u)| = |R_{2n + 1}(u)| \le \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360}\right)^{2n + 2} |u|^{2n + 2}}{(2n + 2)!} \le \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360}\right)^{2n + 2} 180^{2n + 2}}{(2n + 2)!} = \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n + 2}}{(2n + 2)!}$$
on the interval $[-180, 180]$.

Now the obvious thing to do is to let $$f_n(x, y) = \frac{T_{2n + 2}(y)}{T_{2n + 2}(x)}$$ be a sequence of approximations for $f$.

To show $f_n$ is a better approximation than your original one for large enough $n$, we need to prove uniform convergence of some kinds. Unfortunately, $(f_n)$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly on $(0, 180] \times [0, 180]$ because for large enough $n$ and $y = 180$, we have $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f_n(x, y) - f(x, y) = \pm \infty$. Instead, we will show that outside a strip of fixed width $\delta > 0$ near $x = 0$, we can approximate $f$ by $f_n$ as good as we want by choosing a large enough $n$.

---

**Lemma**

For any $\delta > 0$, no matter how small, $(f_n) \to f$ uniformly on $[\delta, 180] \times [0, 180]$.

**Proof**

Let $\delta, \varepsilon > 0$. WLOG assume $\delta, \varepsilon < 1$.

Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2N + 2}}{(2N + 2)!} < \frac{\varepsilon \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{360} \delta}{4}$$
This is possible because $\lim_n \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n + 2}}{(2n + 2)!} = 0$. The same inequality also for holds for all $n \ge N$ because $\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n + 2}}{(2n + 2)!}$ is increasing.

Now for each $n \ge N, x \in (0, 180], y \in [0, 180]$, we have the following:

As $\sin$ is increasing on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, we know $\sin \frac{\pi}{360} x$ is increasing on $[0, 180]$. Therefore, $$\sin \frac{\pi}{360} \delta \le \sin \frac{\pi}{360} x$$ and hence $$\frac{1}{\sin \frac{\pi}{360} x} \ge \frac{1}{\sin \frac{\pi}{360} \delta}$$ on $[\delta, 180]$.

Also,
$$\begin{align}
T_{2n + 2}(x)
&= \sin \frac{\pi}{360} x - R_{2n + 2}(x) \\
&\ge \sin \frac{\pi}{360} \delta - |R_{2n + 2}(x)| \\
&\ge \sin \frac{\pi}{360} \delta - \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n + 2}}{(2n + 2)!} \\
&\ge \sin \frac{\pi}{360} \delta - \frac{\varepsilon \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{360} \delta}{4} \\
&\ge \sin \frac{\pi}{360} \delta - \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{360} \delta}{4} \\
&> \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{360} \delta}{2}
\end{align}$$
and hence $$\frac{1}{T_{2n + 2}(x)} \le \frac{2}{\sin \frac{\pi}{360} \delta}$$ on $[\delta, 180]$.

Combining everything,
$$\begin{align}
|f_n(x, y) - f(x, y)|
&= \left|\frac{T_{2n + 2}(y)}{T_{2n + 2}(x)} - \frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{360} y}{ \sin \frac{\pi}{360} x}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{T_{2n + 2}(y) \sin \frac{\pi}{360} x - T_{2n + 2}(x) \sin \frac{\pi}{360} y}{T_{2n + 2}(x) \sin \frac{\pi}{360} x}\right| \\
&\le \left|\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{360} x \left(T_{2n + 2}(y)  - \sin \frac{\pi}{360} y\right) + \sin \frac{\pi}{360} y \left(\sin \frac{\pi}{360} x - T_{2n + 2}(x)\right)}{T_{2n + 2}(x) \sin \frac{\pi}{360} x}\right| \\
&\le \frac{\left|T_{2n + 2}(y)  - \sin \frac{\pi}{360} y\right| + \left|\sin \frac{\pi}{360} x - T_{2n + 2}(x)\right|}{|T_{2n + 2}(x)| \left|\sin \frac{\pi}{360} x\right|} \\
&\le \frac{2 \cdot \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n + 2}}{(2n + 2)!}}{|T_{2n + 2}(x)| \left|\sin \frac{\pi}{360} x\right|} \\
&\le 2 \cdot \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n + 2}}{(2n + 2)!} \frac{2}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{360} \delta} \\
&< 2 \cdot \frac{\varepsilon \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{360} \delta}{4} \frac{2}{\sin^2 \frac{\pi}{360} \delta} \\
&= \varepsilon
\end{align}$$

---

Let's apply the above to finally get our better approximation :) Say we set $\varepsilon = \delta = 0.0066445 < |f(60, 120) - 1.7386... |$ and choose $N = 8$ such that
$$\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2N + 2}}{(2N + 2)!} < \frac{\varepsilon \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{360} \delta}{4}$$
Then from the above,
$$f_8(x, y) = \frac{\frac{\pi}{360} y - \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} y\right)^3}{3!} + \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} y\right)^5}{5!} - \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} y\right)^7}{7!} \\ + \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} y\right)^9}{9!} - \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} y\right)^{11}}{11!} + \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} y\right)^{13}}{13!} - \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} y\right)^{15}}{15!}}{\frac{\pi}{360} x - \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} x\right)^3}{3!} + \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} x\right)^5}{5!} - \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} x\right)^7}{7!} \\ + \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} x\right)^9}{9!} - \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} x\right)^{11}}{11!} + \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} x\right)^{13}}{13!} - \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{360} x\right)^{15}}{15!}}$$
satisfies $|f_8(x, y) - f(x, y)| < 0.0066445$ on the rectangle $[0.0066445, 180] \times [0, 180]$. Therefore, $f_8$ is a better approximation than your original one on the rectangle $[0.0066445, 180] \times [0, 180]$, which is nearly all of $(0, 180] \times [0, 180]$. As an example, $|f_8(60, 120) - f(60, 120)| = 0.0000081535... < 0.0066445$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks